# Looping over JSON

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to loop over a JSON string in my Android app. This is the code I have so far, using answers I found on line.

```
private void updateAutoComplete() {

        var testJSON = "{result:[{\"symbol\":\"FB\",\"typeDisp\":\"Equity\",\"exchDisp\":\"NASDAQ\",\"exch\":\"NAS\",\"name\":\"Facebook, Inc.\",\"type\":\"S\"},{\"symbol\":\"FB2A.DE\",\"typeDisp\":\"Equity\",\"exchDisp\":\"XETRA\",\"exch\":\"GER\",\"name\":\"Facebook, Inc.\",\"type\":\"S\"}]}";
        var autoCompleteOptions = getAutoCompleteOptions (testJSON);

        ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);

        var autocompleteTextView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.AutoCompleteInput);
        autocompleteTextView.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;
    }

    private String[] getAutoCompleteOptions(String json) {
        var autoCompleteOptions = new String[20];
        int i = 0;
        dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        foreach (var data in dynObj.result) { //x
            autoCompleteOptions.SetValue (data.symbol, i);
            i++;
        }
        return autoCompleteOptions;
    }
```

Want I want is to get the different symbols from the JSON in an array so I can use it for the autocomplete.

When I run the app (updateAutoComplete is called in the OnCreate), I get following error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'result' on the line marked with the x.

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use dynamic anyway? Create a class to hold the results and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to go the route of not serializing back into an object you can cherry pick the data out of the string that you need with a JObject.

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(testJSON);
var result = (JArray)root["result"];

result.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    var symbol = x["symbol"];
    symbol.Dump();
});

//FB
//FB2A.DE
```

Comment: Do you have a using statement for Linq?